# Updating multiple tables in a single sql statement

Tags: mysql

Simple `SQL` syntax question.  I'm writing a script to move data from an old schema to a new one.  I have to switch off the integrity constraints when performing the move so my `CASCASE`s don't work.  I want to update multiple tables with a new value like so:

```
UPDATE table1, table2 
SET table1.customer_id = 999, table2.customer_id = 999;
WHERE table1.customer_id = 3
AND table2.customer_id = 3
```

what's the correct syntax though?  Hopefully the above explains what I want to achieve?  Thanks :).

Comment: Your syntax should also have worked -- once you removed the semicolon after 999.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN table2 USING (customer_id)
SET table1.customer_id = 999, table2.customer_id = 999
WHERE table1.customer_id = 3
```

Never tried it with an update to the key columns like this, but this would work for other columns, so worth a try.